# Generar jornadas de una liga

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

estoy realizando un programa de gestion de ligas de futbol, y me gustaria que geerar automaticamente las jornadas al generar la liga.

Tengo un arraylist de equipo(en principio son 4 equipo, pero cabria la posibilidad de que fuese aumentando, siemre en numeros pares

He conseguido generar una lista de partidos, pero no se como generar las distintas jornadas de las que constara la liga(ida y vuelta a poder ser)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listaEquiposLiga.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listaEquiposLiga.size(); j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                conexionBBDD.nuevoPartido(listaEquiposLiga.get(i).getIdEquipo(), 0, listaEquiposLiga.get(j).getIdEquipo(), 0, null, null, 0);
                };
            };
        };
```

Este seria el método que inserta en la bbdd

public void nuevoPartido(int idEquipoLocal, int golesLocal, int idEquipoVisitante, int golesVisitante, String jugadores, String jugadoresGoles, Integer jornada);

los dos null, son 2 json, que almacenaran los jugadores que juegan y quien ha marcado los goles.

asi es como se mostraria al hacer un select y guardarlo en un arraylist y mostrarlo por pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a solucionarlo.
Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Si preguntas por qué algoritmo usar, eso es una cuestión sobre organización de ligas y no sobre programación (y hay multitud de páginas explicando como hacerlo). Si tienes problemas a la hora de implementar el algoritmo, eso sí que podría ser una pregunta para este sitio.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es una duda funcional, no técnica.

Comment: yo no entiendo cuál es la pregunta

Comment: he encontrdo el algoritmo para generar las jornadas, pero no se como implenetarlo para que coja los nombres de los equipos de un arraylist